# React 0.13.3 can't show a simple thing

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and doing a small tutorial here. When I refresh the browser i should see text "My Component" but there is nothing. Maybe someone can see what I'm missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="link to react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="link to cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
    <title>React components</title>       
</head>
<body>
<div id="react-container"></div>
<script type="text/babel" >
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div>My Component</div>;
        }
    });
    React.render(<MyComponent />, document,getElementById('react-container'));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your `React.render` line. You used a comma instead of a period in `document.getElementById`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I looked at it for too long. Post it as an answer I will approve it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a syntax error in your `React.render` line. You used a comma instead of a period in `document.getElementById`.